# Запрет копирования qr кода

Tags: flutter, dart

Мой вопрос состоит не в помощи кодирования, а именно идеи реализации.

К примеру: есть магазин в котором весит бумажка с QR кодом. Человек сканирует его через  приложения. И вносится в систему.
Как можно предатвратить тот факт. Что человек может, просто сфотографировать код, а потом повторять его сканирования и множество раз вносить код в систему. Что вредит самой системе. Конечно есть две идеи.

1. каждый код имеет свой йади. Что позволит предотвратить повтор.
   Но не удобство в том, что магазину придется после каждого клиента менять картинку кюар кода. Чтобы следущий клиент мог отсканировать, идея отпадает. Так как это совсем не удобно для магазина, никто етим не захочет возиться.
2. можно подключить локацию. И тогда код получает подтверждения только находясь по адресу магазина.
   Но опять же, если клиент додумается, то сможет сфотографировать и с другого телефона сканировать код, находясь возле магазина. Так получится что это не вредит системе но получается обман магазина..
   Кроме того, хоть приложения я почти закончил. А вот с реализацию с локацией, не знаю потяну ли я это.
   долготу и широту.

я могу уже получать. А как перенести эти данные на карту не знаю .

Вопрос Если у кого есть идеи лучше чем придумал я. Буду очень признателен

Comment: Экранчик с одноразовым QR. По факту сканирования система генерит и рисует следующий QR, а предыдущий объявляет использованным.

Comment: Идея хорошая. Я думал об этом . Но! Это мне придется в каждом магазинчике ставить по экранчику.  Как то затратно, для рекламодателя . Спасибо за идею

Comment: *Как то затратно, для рекламодателя* Это вот ты сейчас серьёзно сказал? я ж не имел в виду 32-дюймовый монитор...

Answer (score 0):

Необязательно ставить одноразовый мониторчик, если кьюар остается в системе, значит можно оставить в системе его хеш, или какой-то другой идентефикатор. Да в сами кьюары ты можешь встроить айдишки, и проверять, есть ли уже такой в базе. И если есть, то не давать сканировать повторно, т.е. выводить какую-нибудь ошибку, или что-то в этом роде.

А, да, еще, чтобы не менять кьюары, ты в систему можешь записывать не только сам кьюар, но и айдишку пользователя, который его отсканировал

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).